# How to convert WEI to ETHER php

Tags: php, ethereum

I need to convert string like `0x2fe84e3113d7b` to the float type. This string comes from [infura.io API](https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/json-rpc/eth_getBalance) as balance of the account. I've tried to use https://github.com/mbezhanov/ethereum-converter, but it makes no sense in this case (it always returns 0.00000 in any way). How to convert this string to `0.000842796652117371` with php?

```
use Bezhanov\Ethereum\Converter;

...
$this->converter = new Converter();

$weiValue = '0x1e1e83d93bb6ebb88bbaf';
dump($this->converter->fromWei($weiValue)); // returns 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000

$hexValue = hexdec($weiValue); // returns 2.2757423599815E+24
dump($this->converter->fromWei($hexValue)); // returns the same
```

I guess it caused by too long value on `$hexValue` (I mean converter can't convert long integers as it). But how to get the ether value from this hex?

Comment: Can you show your code where you tried to convert the value?

Comment: @catcon updated the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/w/wei.asp

> 1 Ether = 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 Wei (10^18)

and since this is currency, storing it as a floating point would be asinine, so it's got to be a 64-bit integer there.

Deleted my overwrought answer for a simple:

```
var_dump(
    $wei = hexdec("0x2fe84e3113d7b"),
    $wei / pow(10, 18)
);
```

Output:

```
int(842796652117371)
float(0.000842796652117370993)
```

Which, coincidentally, also illustrates why you don't want to use floats for currency. Also, WFM.

Still doesn't explain why you have:

```
$hexValue = hexdec($weiValue); // returns 2.2757423599815E+24
```

Quoted in your example as that's several orders of magnitude wrong for the supposed input.